# MySQL query help require

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL database. I have employee leave table which having information about employee leave.

Please find table details:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `APPLY_LEAVE` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `EMP_ID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `TYPE_OF_LEAVE` varchar(100) NOT NULL,  
  `DAYS` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `REASON` varchar(200) NOT NULL,  
  `START_DATE` date NOT NULL,
  `END_DATE` date NOT NULL,
  `STATUS` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `CREATED_ON` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `APPLY_LEAVE`
--

INSERT INTO `APPLY_LEAVE` (`ID`, `EMP_ID`, `TYPE_OF_LEAVE`, `DAYS`, `REASON`, `START_DATE`, `END_DATE`, `STATUS`, `CREATED_ON`) VALUES
(1, 'EMP001', 'SL', '2', 'Sick Leave', '2018-11-30', '2018-12-01', 1,'2018-11-06'),
(2, 'EMP002', 'EL', '1', 'Personal', '2018-12-13', '2018-12-13', 1,'2018-11-09'),
(3, 'EMP003', 'CL', '2', 'Casual Leave due to Birthday', '2018-08-31', '2018-09-01', 1,'2018-08-20'),
(4, 'EMP001', 'CL', '3', 'Casual Leave', '2018-12-04', '2018-12-06', 1,'2018-11-27'),
(5, 'EMP002', 'SL', '4', 'Sick Leave', '2018-09-10', '2018-09-13', 1,'2018-10-04'),
(6, 'EMP003', 'SL', '3', 'Sick Leave', '2018-10-30', '2018-11-01', 1,'2018-11-25');
```

**Require Output:** 
I want to generate Report/excel to receive information as month wise employee leave data based on leave type i.e (***Month wise, Leave type data***)
Format should be below:

[image]

**Requirement:** I want MySQL query to fetch attached result month wise, Leave type data(SL/CL/EL) which took by Employee.

---

**Query tries:**

```
SELECT EMP_ID,
SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE_OF_LEAVE = 'EL' AND MONTH( START_DATE ) =11 THEN DAYS ELSE 0 END ) AS EL_NOV,
SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE_OF_LEAVE = 'CL' AND MONTH( START_DATE ) =11 THEN DAYS ELSE 0 END ) AS CL_NOV,
SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE_OF_LEAVE = 'SL' AND MONTH( START_DATE ) =11 THEN DAYS ELSE 0 END ) AS SL_NOV,
SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE_OF_LEAVE = 'LOP' AND MONTH( START_DATE ) =11 THEN DAYS ELSE 0 END ) AS LOP_NOV,
SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE_OF_LEAVE = 'EL' AND MONTH( START_DATE ) =12 THEN DAYS ELSE 0 END ) AS EL_DEC,
SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE_OF_LEAVE = 'CL' AND MONTH( START_DATE ) =12 THEN DAYS ELSE 0 END ) AS CL_DEC,
SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE_OF_LEAVE = 'SL' AND MONTH( START_DATE ) =12 THEN DAYS ELSE 0 END ) AS SL_DEC,
SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE_OF_LEAVE = 'LOP' AND MONTH( START_DATE ) =12 THEN DAYS ELSE 0 END ) AS LOP_DEC
FROM APPLY_LEAVE
GROUP BY EMP_ID
```

**Facing Issue:**
I.e One employee look leave on Friday and Saturday (i.e EMP001 took SL on 2018-11-30 to 2018-12-01) (Friday is month of last date and Saturday is first date of month and I am inserting single record into table. When employee applied leave from application. Here result should be

EMP001 - SL

November - 1 leave

December - 1 leave

How can I write this MySQL query?

Comment: No excel screenshots please. Please frame SQL questions with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: This is not a free write-my-code or do-my-research service. We won't generally just "provide" you with a query. We like to _help_ you with your attempt to solve the problem, and work with your initial code. If you don't try at all you won't learn anything. And if you have tried, please show us, so we don't waste time making the same mistakes again. (If you just want someone to complete the whole job for you with no effort, this is the wrong place to go, instead find a programmer available for hire).

Comment: @ADyson: Sure, i am providing my query. I updated my question. Thank you

Comment: Ok thankyou. Next question - what version of mysql are you running?

Comment: @ADyson  Mysql version 5.6.33-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

Comment: Seriously consider handling this issues of data display in application code.

Comment: It might have been a bit easier to do something like this (or closer to it) with some of the new functionality available in 8.x. But as Strawberry says above, in your current environment, you're probably better just to write a simpler query to get the data out of SQL, and then use application code to process it and create the desired layout.

Comment: @ADyson: Main issue was, I am inserting single row which have two different month of data. I want result into two separate month. How to differentiate from single row. 

I have old legacy data so can't change logic while insert time. if two month then insert two records like.

Comment: What do you mean? Most of the sample data you've shown doesn't cover specific months, it's just arbitrary start and end dates. Again this is a case where your SQL can just output the raw data, and application code can process each row, look at the dates and split it out to increase the count pertaining to each month which overlaps the time period between the start and end. Much much easier to do it in code than in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dear Dipti Kindly find below query for required result.

```
     SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      EMP_ID, 
      START_DATE as date_day, 
      TYPE_OF_LEAVE, 
      SUM(
        if(
          MONTH(START_DATE) <> MONTH(END_DATE), 
          (
            day(
              last_day(START_DATE)
            )+ 1 - day(START_DATE)
          ), 
          days
        )
      ) as DAYS 
    FROM 
      APPLY_LEAVE 
    GROUP BY 
      MONTH(START_DATE), 
      MONTH(END_DATE), 
      EMP_ID 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
      EMP_ID, 
      END_DATE as date_day, 
      TYPE_OF_LEAVE, 
      SUM(
        if(
          MONTH(START_DATE) <> MONTH(END_DATE), 
          DAY(END_DATE), 
          0
        )
      ) as DAYS 
    FROM 
      APPLY_LEAVE 
    GROUP BY 
      MONTH(START_DATE), 
      MONTH(END_DATE), 
      EMP_ID
  ) as a 
WHERE 
  a.DAYS > 0;
```

Comment: you should explain your code so OP understands the problem/solution

Comment: Thank you @Devraj but i am not getting result which i expect. I.e. EMP001 should display SL - 1 in Nov month and second in Dec month. Your provided query skipped other leave data.
I will check with other alternate via application code

Comment: @Dipti kindly check corrected query and confirm me.

Comment: @Devrajverma: Thank you very much. Now you did UNION to merge both data. This is very useful. It's work for me. I will add some more logic as per our template. Thank you very much for quick help